# solve $\int_1^x \frac{1}{t^{2023}-t^{2022}+t^{2021}-t^{2020}} dt$

Tags: definite-integrals

Solve the rational integral $$\int_1^x \frac{1}{t^{2023}-t^{2022}+t^{2021}-t^{2020}} dt.$$

I am trying to solve a IVP and this is the last step to solving it, but I can't get through it. I tried the ordinary method of trying to separate them into fractions. The factorization is $t^{2020}(t^2+1)(t-1)$. With no success.

Comment: The integral does not converge, the integrand behaves like $\frac{1}{2(t-1)}$ near $t=1$.